# How to verify record does not exist in database prior to import?

Tags: sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an importer function that works. The problem is if the record is already in the table it creates a duplicate. There is only one field in the table called mtype. So the CSV file looks like

```
mtype
HP360
Dell
```

The import that is working:

```
require 'csv'
class Modeltype < ApplicationRecord
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Modeltype.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to search to see if the record was in the database with:

```
require 'csv'
class Modeltype < ApplicationRecord
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      tag = row.to_hash
      if Modeltype.find_by_mtype(tag) == nil
        Modeltype.create! row.to_hash
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it like this it returns a "Can't cast hash error."

In the Controller I have:

```
def import
    Modeltype.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to modeltypes_url, notice: "Model Types imported."
end
```

How can I search to see if the record already exists? Then create it if it does not exist and skip that row if it does exist?  I also tried using the flag validates_presence_of, but that also did not work.

I seem to recall using a validates_uniquness_of on a different project before, is this something that might work?

Comment: What specifically is the issue? That `find_by_mtype` and giving it a hash value doesn't find the row?

Comment: Added the error it is throwing to the description, but it says can't cast hash.

Comment: What's that field? Something serialized? (If it's a big table, and that isn't indexed, it'll be an annoying table scan.)

Comment: There is only one field in the table called mtype. Is there a better way to do it? like set the model up to validate uniqueness?

Comment: What's that field? Something serialized?

Comment: It's a string field. After running tag to see what was located in the variable I get "=> {"mtype"=>"HP360"}" so I need to some how parse the hp360 out to search the table if it exists.

Comment: If it's a string why are you converting the row to a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your modeltype.rb file add the line outside of your def but in the class Modeltype `validates_uniqueness_of :mtype`. This will allow the import to work if the item is not in the database. You will need to still build in a catch to skip if the record exists during import. Otherwise you will get an error. So your original def with that line added, like so:

```
require 'csv'
class Modeltype < ApplicationRecord
  validates_uniqueness_of :mtype
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
      Modeltype.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end
end
```